# Connect UITableviewCell with UITableview using Combine repeat values

Tags: swift, swift5, combine

I'm learning combine and I want to use combine instead a delegate between cell and tableview. I have managed to connect and receive the information, but the problem is when the cell is reused, every time I generate the same event, I receive it as many times as it has been used previously in that reused cell.

I have declared cancelables in the view controller as

```
var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
```

And this is the cellForRow method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell.celdaReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        as? MyCell else {
            return MyCell()
    }
    
    cell.index = indexPath
    cell.lbTitle.text = String("Cell \(indexPath.row)")
    
    
    cell.tapButton.compactMap{$0}
        .sink { index in
        print("tap button in cell \(index.row)")
    }.store(in: &cancellables)
    
    return cell
}
```

and the cell is

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
static let cellNibName = "MyCell"
static let celdaReuseIdentifier = "MyCellReuseIdentifier"

@IBOutlet weak var lbTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

var index: IndexPath?

let tapButton = PassthroughSubject<IndexPath?, Never>()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

@IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.tapButton.send(index)
}
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Combine` is overkill. Just use a callback closure `var callback : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?` and call `callback?(self)` in the action. Get the index path from the cell in the closure. With `Combine` you also might have to cancel any subscription when the cell is going off screen.

Comment: @vadian Not necessarily. Just let the OP try it and learn about Combine.

Comment: @matt For educational reasons I agree, for practical reasons I disagree 

Comment: @vadian There is a philosophy of separation of concerns in which Combine is better. Please accept that "Combine is overkill" is just your opinion and your experience speaking. There are other ways. Leave room for them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To solve your problem with reused cells you must add the Set<AnyCancellable> to the cell.

If you are only going to use an event inside cells you can use a single AnyCancellable:

### Single Event (*AnyCancellable*)

Declares a variable in the cell of AnyCancellable Type. Every time the cell is reused a new publisher will be added replacing the previous one and you will not receive the event multiple times.

- #### Cell

  ```
    class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
        static let cellNibName = "MyCell"
        static let celdaReuseIdentifier = "MyCellReuseIdentifier"

        @IBOutlet weak var lbTitle: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

        var index: IndexPath?

        // store publisher here
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable? 

        // Single Publisher per cell
        let tapButton = PassthroughSubject<IndexPath?, Never>()

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
        }

        @IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) {
            self.tapButton.send(index)
        }
    }
  ```
- #### ViewController

In the Viewcontroller you just have to add the publisher to the cancellable.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell.celdaReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    as? MyCell else {
        return MyCell()
    }

    cell.index = indexPath
    cell.lbTitle.text = String("Cell \(indexPath.row)")

    // Add your publisher to your cancellable and remove store function.

    cell.cancellable =  cell.tapButton.compactMap{$0} .sink { index in
        print("tap button in cell \(index.row)")
    }

    return cell
}
```

### Multiples events (*Set<AnyCancellable>*)

Here it is the same but using a collection in case you want to have more events than just one.

- #### Cell

Create a variable Set<AnyCancellable> to store the publishers.
In this case, before reusing the cell, we will have to remove the cancellables before creating new ones.

```
    class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
        static let cellNibName = "MyCell"
        static let celdaReuseIdentifier = "MyCellReuseIdentifier"
    
        @IBOutlet weak var lbTitle: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    
        var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable>?

        var index: IndexPath?
    
    // Multiple Publishers per cell
        let tapButton = PassthroughSubject<IndexPath?, Never>()
        let tapView = PassthroughSubject<UIImage, Never>()

    // Remove all suscriptions before reuse cell
        override func prepareForReuse() {
            super.prepareForReuse()
            cancellables.removeAll()
         }

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }
    
        @IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) {
            self.tapButton.send(index)
        }
    }
```

- #### ViewController

In the Viewcontroller you just have to store the publishers.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell.celdaReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        as? MyCell else {
            return MyCell()
    }
    
    cell.index = indexPath
    cell.lbTitle.text = String("Cell \(indexPath.row)")
    
    // Add your publisher to your cell´s collection of AnyCancellable
    
    cell.tapButton.compactMap{$0}
        .sink { index in
        print("tap button in cell \(index.row)")
    }.store(in: &cell.cancellables)
    
      return cell
 }
```

Good Luck!!

Comment: I didn't understand the part of clearing the cancellables in prepareForReuse, why do I need to remove the cancellables every time the cell is reused?

Comment: Because cells are reusable. And if you won't clean the bag - the bag will always grow when u scroll your table view and cells are getting reusable. The main problem is that if you will initiate some action in cell - it will be called as much times as the count of subscriptions in your bag)

Answer (score 2):

You have analyzed and described the problem perfectly. And so the cause is clear. Look at your `cellForRow` implementation and think about what it does: You are *creating and adding a **new** pipeline* to your `cancellables` *every* time your `cellForRow` runs, regardless of whether you've *already* added a pipeline for this instantiation of the cell.

So you need a way not to do that. Can you think of a way? Hint: attach the pipeline to the *cell* and vend it from there, so there is *only one* per cell. Your Set won't add *the same* pipeline twice, because it is a Set.

Comment: do you have any resources to deeply understand why it is needed to clear the cancellables in prepareForReuse function as mentioned in the previous answer?

Comment: @AhmedBahgat That is exactly what my answer tells you.